# Webdriver how to close the browser after The operation has timed out

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, internet-explorer-9, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

After time out i am not able to close the browser ,No matter what i do even if call `browser.Quit()`.The browser just hangs around forever .I am working with IE browser 9 and the latest web driver 2.37.0
This happens when we have time out , an example error as follows

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58542/session/0f8faf36-f84f-4035-9cc0-169656bc00c6/element/c841d512-c9ff-4d2a-9a45-87f52359d986/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

I would like to know if any work around for this issue is available ,closing the browser manually is not optimal option like what i am doing now .Thank you in advance and if you need any more info please let me know

Comment: Are you using a unit-test style framewotk? So `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods? Just ensure that you `.quit()` within your `tearDown()` method.

Comment: Hi i am using n-unite i have declared the   '.quit()' in 'teardown()' it gets executed but nothing happens :( , i have no idea why this happening

Comment: Does the error happen in the setup method? Are you debugging with Visual Studio when this happens?

Comment: This happens during the test run,when some element is not located or when i am using javascript